# SalesForce to emulate a google session login

Tags: salesforce, google-data-api, google-docs, google-authentication

I'm pretty new to SalesForce and their Apex language. I've been reading some documentation and tried the integration between Google and SalesForce.

I'm wondering is it possible to emulate an auth token from google to SalesForce?

I'm trying to read a google spreadsheet and then fill up a SalesForce object automatically. The user login will always be the same/universal for this spreadsheet, so I have the credentials required to login. 
I am working off of the sample that requires a visualforce, and I'm wondering how would I automatically do the session id token that the google spreadsheet API requires.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old-school, hard way would be to send a [login()](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/sforce_api_calls_login.htm?SearchType=Stem) call to the API (available through SOAP messages). Salesforce API is well documented and plenty of examples are available (both in programming languages and for [raw XML requests/responses](http://wiki.developerforce.com/index.php/Sample_SOAP_Messages_%2810.0_API%29)).

But I have no idea what possibilities you have from Google side, if it's only JavaScript then you might not be able to send and retrieve AJAX-like calls to another domain...

Recently another option emerged and that is REST API (no SOAP needed). Looks more promising and easier in my opinion. Quick intro is available [here](http://wiki.developerforce.com/index.php/Getting_Started_with_the_Force.com_REST_API) and you'll find more documentation on the bottom of the page.

Last but not least - 2 interesting links:
http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/articles/salesforce.html for some integration tutorial
and built-in integration offered by Salesforce: http://www.salesforce.com/assets/pdf/datasheets/SalesforceGoogleApps.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, however, I was trying to get this to be done automatically in salesforce itself. Having a trigger run apex code after an object is created. So there's no need for the login() to get into salesforce. Which is why I want to know if it's possible to make it programmatically login to a certain google account (not necessarily the one currently logged into SalesForce).

Comment: Wait... you want to access google apps from salesforce or other way around :) If you don't need logging in, then maybe you could use the Inbound & Outbound Messaging mechanism in Salesforce. Essentially it will send or accept an XML message sent to special URL. Inbound message sent to Salesforce could be automatically processed by your Apex class and result in insertion of data. If outbound msg to Google is also an option for you - great. Maybe we should use Stack Overflow chat to clarify your question, when you'd have time (and in what timezone :P)

Comment: Access a google app from salesforce. However, since this is hosted on salesforce, and will be ran as a trigger, I don't believe I need to login.
Sure, whenever you have the time to chat, it'd be great. I'm on EST, and anytime from 9-11, 2-6 on weekdays is usually good.

Comment: I'll do my best to be camping out there for you on http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/294/salesforce-com every work day this week. I'm in Europe (GMT+1) minus 5 hrs means evenings for me :)

Answer (score 1):

I've used custom settings to do this. Use OAuth to get a token for Google, then store that token in Salesforce custom settings (Setup-Develop-Custom Settings). You can then retrieve the token for callouts to Google from that custom setting for any user needing access to Google Apps. The downside is, every user will authenticate as your custom setting token user. The upside is that they won't need to individually authenticate. Custom settings are retrievable via Apex using a simple getter, and live as Apex-like objects.

Also keep in mind, Google requires each service to use it's own token. So, if your user wants to use Calendars and Spreadsheets, that's two separate tokens that will need to be stored and retrieved for the callout.

I generally allow users to create their own authenticated session tokens via OAuth if they want to do that, then failover to the custom settings to get the general admin token if necessary.

Comment: I'll be trying this on Friday when I have time again! I'll respond to you then! I hope this works, it sounds like it'll work which is getting my all giddy! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to log into Google Apps from SFDC? There are options for Google Apps within Salesforce, go to Setup > Administration Setup > Google Apps > Settings. I've not used this and it requires some setup, but thought I'd point it out. Aside from that I can only blurt out OAuth (getting users to authenticate with Google from within Salesforce when trying to access Google Apps) and SSO (which I know can be used to authenticate from an external system, though not sure if it works the other way).

Comment: The settings is just to point salesforce to the correct google app domain, which doesn't allow me to specify a user for general salesforce to google app connection. I don't want the users to use OAuth because it should be done programmatically, and this is going to be ran as apex code, and as a trigger with no need of user intervention

Answer (score 0):

Look into the "Named Credentials" menu in salesforce setup. 
There, you can store auth credentials for the services accessed via Apex:

"A named credential specifies a callout endpoint and its required authentication parameters. When setting up callouts, avoid setting authentication parameters for each callout by referencing named credentials."

a username/pass combo can be used, or a certificate, or an AWS signature, and there is a JWT option..

Help docs: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=named_credentials_about.htm&type=5